# Shift a column based on value of another column in R data.table

Tags: r, data.table

consider the following case, where I'm trying to use shift to get `v2` -> `Target_v3`

```
library(data.table)
dt = data.table(v1=c(1,0,1,1,0),
                v2=letters[1:5],
                Target_v3=c(NA,"b","b","c","e"))
> dt
   v1 v2 Target_v3
1:  1  a        NA
2:  0  b         b
3:  1  c         b
4:  1  d         c
5:  0  e         e
```

What I need is a new column `v3`, which is the value in `v2`, lagged by the number `v1` - as in `Target_v3`

I have tried using shift, but not able to get what I want, e.g.
`dt[, v3 := shift(v2, v1, type="lag")]` seems wrong, and gives the wrong result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what about a silly solution like this?

```
dt[, v3 := sapply(1:nrow(dt),function(i){v2[i-v1[i]]})]
```

[image]

Comment: just noticed that its essentially the same idea: `dt[, v3 := v2[ifelse(.I-v1 <= 0, NA_integer_, .I - v1)]]`

Comment: @chinsoon12 in case `v1` is binary, you solution will by far more superior IMO.